# extracting a specific part of a url using regex

Tags: java, regex, url, uri, extract

i wanna extract a part of url which is at the middle of it, by using regex in java
this is what i tried,mostly the problem to detect `java+regex`is that its in the middle of last part of url and i have no idea how to ignore the characters after it, my regex just ignoring before it:

```
   String regex = "https://www\\.google\\.com/(search)?q=([^/]+)/";
String   url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=regex+java&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile (regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher (url);

if (matcher.matches ())
{
    int n = matcher.groupCount ();
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
        System.out.println (matcher.group (i));
}
    }
```

the result should be `regex+java` or even `regex java` . but my code didnt work out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
    String regex = "https://www\\.google\\.com/search\\?q=([^&]+).*";
    String   url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=regex+java&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile (regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher (url);

    if (matcher.matches ())
    {
        int n = matcher.groupCount ();
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
            System.out.println (matcher.group (i));
    }
```

The result is:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=regex+java&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a
regex+java
```

**EDIT**

Replacing all pluses before printing:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
   String str = matcher.group (i).replaceAll("\\+", " ");
   System.out.println (str);
}
```

Comment: and by any chance, is there anyway to replace + with a whitepace at same time?

Comment: You'd have to do `System.out.println(matcher.group(i).replace('+', ' '));`

Comment: but how about a permanant one? should i restore it in a string then use replace('+',' ')? or better way?

Comment: but its giving error for me, did u try the edit part of ur answer?

Comment: Obviously I didn't I made similar error to your initial one. I fixed it now.

Comment: yea, confused regex form with string form :)...thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String regex = "https://www\\.google\\.com/?(search)\\?q=([^&]+)?";
    String url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=regex+java&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);

    while (matcher.find()) {

        System.out.println(matcher.group());


    }
```

This  should do your job.